# c# listBox.GetItemText broken

Tags: c#, listbox

This is in a `for` statement

```
listBox2.SelectedIndex = b;
vGame = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
```

This works,  however I don't want to use the `SelectedIndex` because I have a data loaded when you click an item in the list,   so I tried:

```
vGame = listBox2.GetItemText(b);
```

and the value is just 0,  how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you need other formatting?

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it fixed finally,  I tried a bunch of things but after looking up the GetItemText they had an example of Items as array [],  I tried () (I'm so used to vb6)

this works:
vGame = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.Items[b]);